# Image in FloatingActionButton has to be changed on click and back

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

```
public void ImageButtonChange1(View view){
    FloatingActionButton imageButton = new FloatingActionButton(getApplicationContext());
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            boolean flag = true;
            if (flag) {
                imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.microphone_off);
                flag = false;
            } else {
                imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.microphone_active);
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

What's wrong in my code that the application is crashing. I've tried almost everything i think

Answer (score 0):

Try this once

```
public void ImageButtonChange1(View view){
        FloatingActionButton imageButton = new FloatingActionButton(getApplicationContext());
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                boolean flag = true;
                if (flag) {
    imageButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext() , R.drawable.microphone_off));
                    flag = false;
                } else {
               
    imageButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext() , R.drawable.microphone_active));
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
        });
```